# Is not meeting an agreed upon deadline a sin?

Tags: obligation, human-rights

I work as a Freelancer. I recently got into a contract with a client, we set up a deadline, and I agreed that I will deliver on the aforementioned deadline. But due to my own lack of competence, I came no way near to that goal.
Keep in mind that I took absolutely no payment from the client. And also didn't deliver any work. Is repenting to Allah SWT enough in this case? Or will I be held responsible even after repenting sincerely?

JazakAllah Khair.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu Alaikum brother

I'd like to tell you one thing that "Jannah is full of sinners who sincerely repent to Allah".

That's life, you sin - you repent.

The most crutial part after repentence (tauba), is to make sure that you never commit that sin again.

May Allah grant you the ability to ask forgiveness sincerely.
Ameen.

Answer (score -1):

This is a temporal matter and not a spiritual one. It's not a situation where one can speak of sin or not. It simply does not apply. The apologies you should make is to your client.